# Can we worship Vastu Purusha normally?

Tags: identification-request, worship, vastu

Vastu Shanti Puja is a ritual for Vastu Purusha and also please him. But, Can we worship him normally, like other deities? Is Vastu worship can be suitable in temple?

Comment: Before beginning the construction of any structure for residence & congregation, (for both religious & secular use), Hindu scriptures direct the constructor to perform Vastu-Puja in order to remove ill-omens. However a temple for worshipping Vastu is unheard & not mentioned. The term 'Vastu-Puja' is a misnomer, because the main object of adoration are the 64 (or 81) celestial beings who collectively stand upon the subdued demon named Vastu.